# How to show different options based on if user is logged in or not?

Tags: php

Here is what I have

```
<?php
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

$checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
    $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

    $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
}

if(empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
?>
    <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>

<?php
}
else {
    echo "Hello $username";   
}
?>
```

The Login and Signup Links work, my database database is connected and working as well, I can't get the username to show up instead of login and signup when the user is logged in.

http://strandev2.net46.net/index.php

Comment: `session_start();` at the top? And you should only do the database stuff when an actual POST request is made and use the session variables otherwise.

Comment: Yep, it's there. Okay.

Comment: try isset instead of empty

Comment: By the way, using an un-salted `md5` for your passwords is a very bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Comment: That partially worked, now Hello shows, however username still doesn't.

Comment: Are you using your session variable instead of the posted version?

Comment: What do you mean jeroen, aren't you supposed to you $_SESSION? I'm very new to php.

Comment: `echo "Hello {$_SESSION['Username']}";` or `echo "Hello " . $_SESSION['Username'];` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code

```
if(empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && empty($_SESSION['Username']))
```

with

```
if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && isset($_SESSION['Username']))
```

Also put your else part in same php tag.